# Bombardier - Read from file

Tags: performance-testing, benchmarking, load-testing

Is there a way to have the benchmarking tool Bombardier read portion of input from a file and substitute this in the request body?

I want to test for x number of ID's with rest of the request body being the same. As an example

**bombardier -c 10 -d 200s -m POST -b {"id": < fromfile >, "somefield": "yes"}  http://localhost:8080**

How can the above value < from file > be replaced by the actual file contents?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems the obvious strategy is to create a new file from your input file that has only the number of records you want. If it's a text file, look at using the "head" command. Is there a reason not to do that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I have around 500K requests to test - and except for 1 field, everything else in the request body is the same.  As a result, did not want the input file to have the same repeated information for all requests. 

I don't see "head" command listed in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that "head" is a Linux/Unix command. It's also on Macintoshes, but not on Windows. It lets you list the first lines (you can specify any number) from a text file. If you can use "head", you can combine it with other tools like awk or xargs to create custom temporary files for testing.

Comment: is there any solution for importing by text file or import from insomnia or postman?